# How to model optional inheritance in Java

Tags: java, oop

Is there a way optional inheritance as described in the following case?

Say start with this:

[image]

Note: there are can be more than 4 child classes.

Now there is an optional capability called "Autonomous Transport" as here.

[image]

Option 1: As in this picture above I can have all child classes inherit from "Autonomous Transport" but I don't want that. Say, there cannot be an autonomous Train.

Option 2: Not have "Autonomous Transport" strictly in between but have individual classes inherit (may be with interface) like "Car", "Autonomous Car", "Truck", "Autonomous Truck" as needed. But not an attractive option as there are way more than 4 child classes

Option 3: Possibly, I can use dependency injection and inject "Autonomous" capability where needed but I cannot add any framework like dagger etc.

Are there any other ways, it can be done cleanly with Java? Basically, if "Train" cannot be autonomous, I do not want any related business logic there.

Comment: You could also use a Decorator pattern.  Have an `AutonomousTransport` that wraps any `Transport` and provides the features needed for autonomous operation.

Comment: Most surely, you don't need inheritance to model this. Whenever you have the chance, prefer composition over inheritance. You might have an attribute `private AutonomousCapability autonomy`, where you might place all data and behavior

Comment: Similar to Option 2, but why not have Car, Truck and Airplain inherit from AutonomousTransport and Train directly inherit from Transport? Or can there be non-autonomous Cars in your model (this is not completely clear from Option 1)?

Answer (score 3):

To keep it simple:

**Option 1**

```
abstract class Transport {
   foo();
} 

abstract class AutomonousTransport extends Transport {
   bar();
}

class Car extends AutonomousTransport {
   // inherits foo and bar
}

class Train extends Transport {
   //inherits only foo(), which is ok, since Train is still a transport 
}
```

With this approach you'll have to decide from which class to inherit so that you'll get the desired capabilities.

The potential drawback of this method is if you have many different capabilities like this (and in java you can extend only from one class).

To overcome this issue, if you only inherit *the capability* (behavior) and not the state, consider using interfaces with default methods instead of abstract classes. This works somewhat like Traits in other languages with some restrictions:

```
interface Transport {
   default foo () {...} 
}

interface AutonomousTransport extends Transport {
   default bar() {}
}
interface WheelSupportTransport extends Transport {
   default rotateWheelLeft() {...}
   default rotateWheelRight() {...}
}

class Car implements AutomonousTransport, WheelSupportTransport  {
   
}

class Train implements Transport {...}
```

**Option 2**

```
abstract class Transport {
   foo() 
}

final class AutonomousStuff { // final to prohibit inheritance from it
   bar()
}

class Car extends Transport {
   AutonomousStuff autonomousStuff;
}

class Train extends Transport {
   // only foo
}
```

This approach is based on "prefere composition over inheritance" idea. You add the behavior to the required class as an internal data field and gain the access to the required set of methods (capabilities) through this field.

**Option 3**

```
abstract class Transport {
   foo()
}

abstract class AutonomousCapable extends Transport {
    private final Transport transport;
    public AutonomouseCapable(Transport transport) {
       this.transport  =  transport;
    }
    bar()

    foo() {
        transport.foo();
    }
    
}

class Car extends Transport {}

class Train extends Transport {}
```

When creating the car, use `new AutonomousCapable(new Car())`

This follows the idea of "decorator" (a.k.a. wrapper) pattern. You "decorate" the object (car) with additional set of behaviors in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If Autonomous is an optional capability then it is actually not a generalized property of all its subclasses.

In my opinion, it would be 4 abstract classes `AbstractCar`, `AbstractTruck` etc. And then you can have two concrete implementations of each of these Abstract classes, say `AutonomousCar` and `NonAutonomousCar`. One autonomous and the other not.

And you can have a marker interface for the Autonomous classes called `IAutonomousTransport`

Of course, the above assumes that you don't want a simple flag called `isAutonomous` within your class and handle your functionality based on that. But this method wouldn't be polymorphic.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) here:

```
public interface Transport {
    void foo();
}

public class AutonomousTransport implements Transport {
    public void foo() {
        // autonomous transport implementation
    }
}

public class Car implements Transport {
    private final Transport delegate;
    
    public Car(Transport delegate) {
        this.delegate delegate;
    }
    
    public void foo() {
        if(delegate == null)
            // car transport implementation
        else
            delegate.foo();
    }
    
}
```

***P.S.** This snippet shows you a brief solution. It could be many variants of implemnetation of this pattern.*

> **Option 1:** As in this picture above I can have all child classes
> inherit from "Autonomous Transport" but I don't want that. Say, there
> cannot be an autonomous Train.

Think about replace `inheritance` to `delegation`. In most of the cases, delegation is more preferable.

> **Option 2:** Not have "Autonomous Transport" strictly in between but have
> individual classes inherit (may be with interface) like "Car",
> "Autonomous Car", "Truck", "Autonomous Truck" as needed. But not an
> attractive option as there are way more than 4 child classes

`Autonomous Transport` look to me like **behavior**, but not property. I am sure, that it should not be in the `Transport` hierarhy.

> **Option 3:** Possibly, I can use dependency injection and inject
> "Autonomous" capability where needed but I cannot add any framework
> like dagger etc.

[Dipendency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is pattern but not a framework like Spring or Dagger. If your class contains linke to another class (does not matter via constructor or setter), de-facto this is DI already.